# Marker taps are not always recognized android

Tags: android, google-maps

I have included Google Map in my app and added 4 markers in the map by using a for loop. I also managed to get the zip code, the name of the city and the adress of these added markers by using Geocoder.

It all works, but the problem is that clicks on the markers do not always seem to work. Sometimes I have to make double taps to see the title of the markers. I really don't know why. Here is my full code

```
     public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    String city, adress, zip;
    Marker marker;
    LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;    

        LatLng[] point_new = new LatLng[4];
        point_new[0] = new LatLng(52.4788535, 13.32730760000004);
        point_new[1] = new LatLng(52.4794297, 13.313520799999992);
        point_new[2] = new LatLng(52.5272885, 13.458033200000045);
        point_new[3] = new LatLng(52.52603999999999, 13.488159999999993);

        for (int i = 0; i < point_new.length; i++) {
            drawMarker(point_new[i]);

                  marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point_new[i]));

           mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(point_new[i]));


        }
        getAdress(52.4788535, 13.32730760000004 );
        marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point_new[0]).title(adress+"," + zip + "" + city));

        getAdress(52.4794297, 13.313520799999992);
        marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point_new[1]).title(adress+"," + zip + "" + city));

        getAdress(52.5272885, 13.458033200000045);
        marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point_new[2]).title(adress+"," + zip + "" + city));

        getAdress(52.52603999999999, 13.488159999999993);
         marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point_new[3]).title(adress+"," + zip + "" + city));

        for (int j = 0; j < point_new.length; j++) {
            builder.include(point_new[j]);    
        }


        LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 20));

    }


    public void drawMarker(LatLng point) {
        // Creating an instance of MarkerOptions
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

        // Setting latitude and longitude for the marker
        markerOptions.position(point);

        // Adding marker on the Google Map
        mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    }

    public void getAdress(double lat, double lng){
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(MapsActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());

        List<Address> addresses  = null;
        try {

            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat,lng,1);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
         adress = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
         zip = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> try this code, i have tested, its working

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        List<MarkerDesc> markerDescList = new ArrayList<>();
        markerDescList.add(new MarkerDesc(new LatLng(52.4788535, 13.32730760000004), getAdress(52.4788535, 13.32730760000004)));
        markerDescList.add(new MarkerDesc(new LatLng(52.4794297, 13.313520799999992), getAdress(52.4794297, 13.313520799999992)));
        markerDescList.add(new MarkerDesc(new LatLng(52.5272885, 13.458033200000045), getAdress(52.5272885, 13.458033200000045)));
        markerDescList.add(new MarkerDesc(new LatLng(52.52603999999999, 13.488159999999993), getAdress(52.52603999999999, 13.488159999999993)));

        for(int i=0; i<markerDescList.size(); i++){
            MarkerDesc markerDesc = markerDescList.get(i);

            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(markerDesc.getLatLng())
                    .title(markerDesc.getAddresses().get(0).getLocality())
                    .snippet(markerDesc.getAddresses().get(0).getAddressLine(0)+"\n"+markerDesc.getAddresses().get(0).getPostalCode()+"\n"+markerDesc.getAddresses().get(0).getLocality())
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker()));
        }
        LatLng latLng = markerDescList.get(markerDescList.size()-1).getLatLng();
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(new CameraPosition.Builder().target(latLng).zoom(15).bearing(0).tilt(25).build()));


    }


    public List<Address> getAdress(double lat, double lng){
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(MapsActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            return geocoder.getFromLocation(lat,lng,1);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        /*String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
        String adress = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
        String zip = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();*/

        return  null;
    }


    private class MarkerDesc{
        LatLng latLng;
        List<Address> addresses;

        private MarkerDesc(LatLng ltLng, List<Address> addr){
            this.latLng=ltLng;
            this.addresses = addr;
        }

        private LatLng getLatLng() {
            return latLng;
        }

        private List<Address> getAddresses() {
            return addresses;
        }



    }

}
```